# Read in Data in any format, write to table

Tags: xml, normalization

I was wondering, has anyone ever heard of any tool (open source) that reads in data across multiple formats (CSVs, XML, database tables, etc.), and normalizes it into a single format (like an Oracle table or whatever)?

For example we have customers that send us financial data and I was hoping that there was something out there that I could leverage and contribute to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Kettle (aka Pentaho Data Integration) for this (and many other data forging things).

It's open source (used to be LGPL, recently switched to Apache 2.0 license) and comes with support for many input formats (JSON, CSV, LDAP, XML, Excel and so on) and many databases (+30 out of the box)

Tutorial: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Pentaho+Data+Integration+(Kettle)+Tutorial
Download: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/

(You'll need Java 6)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but ETL may be what you're looking for : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load